# date information in another language

Tags: nodes

In order to display the date information in French, I have modified the node.tpl.php file as follows.

```
 print t('publi&eacute; le !datetime',
      array('!datetime' => format_date($variables['node']->created, $type='medium', $format = 'D j F Y', $timezone = NULL, $langcode = 'fr'))
 );
```

The week day, and the month are still displayed in English!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your template.php file.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
}
```

You might need to add this to your node.page.tpl file.

```
$variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted on !datetime', array('!datetime' => $variables['date']));
```

The source is [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1072640).

Comment: My drupal site is in english ! I know this solution but it doesn't work !! I need $langcode = 'fr'

Comment: It seems that the format_date ignores the $language parameter ?

Comment: Day of week and month are always in english !